# Is the word yolk used appropriately for the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

**The sentence in question:**

- Will the hunter regret tricking a lovely girl? Even if the girl is the yolk of a disgusting monster that killed her parents?

---

I am asking this question because my mind says that it is okay to use the word yolk like this, but my research says something different, I came here asking because I am confused.

Though, if the word yolk shouldn't be used in the sentence provided, then, if possible, please give me a list of a few possible words that would suit that position in the sentence.

Also, the context of the way I am using the word yolk is one's child. After all, the hunter's parents were killed by the girl's father. So the girl would be the child of a disgusting monster that killed the hunter's parents.

---

So for the full context, here is the entire paragraph that the word yolk was used in (the word yolk will be bolded):

A story of monsters, two lovely girls, one loves, while the other uses. Is it willing love or something much much darker? A hunter knows no bounds to kill her target, she will get what she wants, but is it the right choice, will she regret tricking a lovely girl? Even if the girl is the **yolk** of a disgusting monster that killed her parents?

Comment: Perhaps you could update the question to include the definition of *yolk* that you’ve found that you think could allow this usage and then discuss why you are unsure if it can be applied in your context.

Comment: @Jim That's the thing, all that I could find on the definition of the yolk is that it is the yellow part of an egg. Also, I don't really know why I think why it can be used like this. Hence why I am unsure, as I said, my mind says one thing, but my research says another. I did try to find a definition that allows this but I hadn't come across one, so I posted a question here. The only thing I can say is that my mind thinks that yolk can also mean one's child, but I don't know if it is an actual meaning of the word yolk.

Comment: Offspring works here. Think of this: most monsters are not associated with eggs though some do come from them. Would you say that in your native language?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was the one who upvoted your answer and I don't need to be told that offspring is neutral. I know that. However, we know already the monster is disgusting. It is just another option.

Comment: In order to use *yolk* here, you will need a more elaborate metaphor, which is probably more than you want to do.  If something-or-other is the egg, then the girl is the yolk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Yolk*** is completely wrong in OP's context, but ***spawn*** is fine. It's [very common with devils](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spawn%20of%20the%20devil%2Cyolk%20of%20the%20devil&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) as well as monsters..

[image]

Per [@Lambie's comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/599190/is-the-word-yolk-used-appropriately-for-the-following-sentence/599191#comment1508492_599190), ***offspring*** has the same basic meaning (child, scion, spawn) - but it's *neutral*, whereas ***spawn*** is almost always *negative, derogatory*.

Comment: [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/spawn) says "often derogatory" and "usually contemptuous" of this use of spawn, if you need more evidence.